# Upsampling a sequence

Tags: c#, system.reactive

How can an a RX sequence be *upsampled*,  ie make it trigger more frequently?

The .Sample operator only allows downsampling:

```
IObservable<long> source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(5000));
IObservable<long> trigger = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000));

//var triggeredSource = source.Sample(trigger);
var triggeredSource = source.Sample(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(1000)); 

source.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
triggeredSource.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine);
```

Here triggeredSource fires only  every 5000ms and not 1000ms. We want:

```
source:  ----a----b----c----d------
trigger: -o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o-o
result:  ----aa-a-b-b-bcc-c-d-d-d-d
```

How can this be done?

Comment: Your example is confusing, two events can't happen at exactly the same time (e.g. `b` from source and trigger at the same time).

Comment: One method that works is:

var triggeredSource = source.CombineLatest(trigger,(sourceVal,triggerVal)=>sourceVal);

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: Why do you think that's inefficient? Have you measured that it's actually a problem for you? Otherwise you have short, readable way to do exactly what you want, so you should use it.

Answer (score 2):

You can get the behavior you want using `CombineLatest` - conceptually, it's a `Get Last Value` plus a `Merge`:

[edit: only realized after posting you mention this in a comment - it's likely the most 'efficient' way you'll get]

```
IObservable<long> source = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(500));
IObservable<long> trigger = Observable.Interval(TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(100));

var triggeredSource = source.CombineLatest(trigger, (src, trig) => src);

using(triggeredSource.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine))
{
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```